# How to get the maximum value in a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as follows, with different keys and values.

```
lst = [{'a': 15554}, {'v': 453}, {'a': 441742}, {'vb': 7785}, 
         {'vv': 4275}, {'g': 7822}, {'l': 47537}, {'fg': 1144441565}]
```

I want to find which dictionary contains the highest value using python.
Ex:
`fg: 1144441565`

can somebody suggest me a code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It pretty much boils down to: how to get the first and only value from a dict without knowing the key. Once you figure that out, you simply  use that as key function in `max(list1, key=...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `max`:

```
max(list1, key=lambda x: list(x.values()))
# {'fg': 1144441565}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply by looping though the list of dictionaries and checking the value each time:

```
# Define the list
list1 = [{'a': 15554}, {'v': 453}, {'a': 441742}, {'vb': 7785}, 
{'vv': 4275}, {'g': 7822}, {'l': 47537}, {'fg': 1144441565}]

# Init variable to hold the maximum value and its corresponding key. 
# We just initialize it as the value of the first element:
max_val_key = list1[0].keys()[0]
max_val = list1[0][max_val_key]

# Loop through it using the 'in' operator
for dict in list1:
    key = dict.keys()[0]
    val = dict[key]

    # Check if current val is higher than the last defined max_val
    if (val > max_val):
        max_val = val
        max_val_key = key
```